# scim claim mapping to apache ds

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have install apache ds with default installation, and configure wso2 identification server to connect to apache ds.
I can login with wso2 is with apache ds username/password.

I guess that it is caused by scim claim. Can somebody give some suggestion?
BTW:  wsois4.6, apache ds 2.0.0.

when I run
curl -v -k --user admin:secret     https://www.local.com:9443/wso2/scim/Users

The response is following:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not see the error that you have mentioned. However, once Server is connected to external user store,  you need to map claims according to the your user store attributes. By default,  attributes are mapped for the claim; according to the default user store (embedded LDAP). You can change the default claim mapping using claim management UI of WSO2IS. You could find more detail from [here](http://soasecurity.org/2012/05/02/claim-management-with-wso2-identity-server/) about claim management. You can select desired existing attribute name that is available in the user object class in ApacheDS.

Comment: great information, that's what I want to get the claim mapping management for apacheDS

Comment: Is there any existing claim mapping for apache ds?